# Is there a way to use express to get the id of the device through which a particular request was sent?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I need this option to remember the device ID used when registering a new user and save it in the database, and later when logging in, if another device is used, the user needs to send a verification email to be able to log in to their account.

This is a similar feature as google uses for its Gmail.

Comment: Express can only used this id  when it gets it, you need a `front app/web` to serve you this id, which may include ip address, imei etc

Comment: No deviceID is automatically sent with any http request from a browser so your Express server will not have access to a deviceID.  If the client wants to cooperate, it can add a deviceID as a custom header or a query string parameter or a cookie and then the server can access that.

Comment: Login would generally be done with a cookie, not a deviceID.  Some services will detect if this looks like a different device than was previously logged in.  This is done with "device fingerprinting" algorithms.  It is not an exact science and cannot be used for login by itself, but can be used to help decide when to ask for secondary verification.  If you want to  know more about how it works, search Google for "Device Fingerprinting" and there are lots of articles on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If your application works on web than you can fetch the user-agent information  and the user IP address and create a hash details using his combination. If the hash is different in the 2nd attempt of sign-in / login than you can do you desired action

Comment: An IP address is a crummy proxy for a deviceID since devices can move around the network (and thus change IP address) and many devices can share the same IP address via NAT.  Just look at two separate users from the same home network.  They will both appear to be coming from the same IP address.  The same can be true on corporate networks.